# PHP 8.0: How to apply xdebug.ini

Tags: linux, centos, xdebug, xdebug-3

I installed Xdebug 3.0 on CentOS, but I don't want to use it by modifying `php.ini`. I want to create a new `xdebug.ini` to load Xdebug.

How can I do this?

```
> php -v
PHP 8.0.6 (cli) (built: May 26 2021 16:08:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `php --ini | grep additional` it will tell you a directory name, as in:

```sh
derick@mezcal:~$ php --ini | grep additional
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
```

You can then place an `xdebug.ini` file, preferably as `99-xdebug.ini` into this directory with the Xdebug settings that you need.

You can then verify whether this works, by running `php --ini | grep xdebug`, and it should list the file that you have created:

```sh
derick@mezcal:~$ php --ini | grep xdebug
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini
```